# What is the difference between writing React component opening and closing inline and in different lines?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

When I was creating a Multiselect dropdown using Material-ui, I stuck into something strange.
If I provide select list item like this:

```
let rows = this.props.masterList.map(item => (
  <MenuItem key={item.key} value={item.key}> {item.value} </MenuItem>
))
```

It shows props.children element as an array of 3 items
[image]

The output is coming with commas following the text:
[image]

If I write the same code with new lines like this :

```
let rows = this.props.masterList.map(item => (
  <MenuItem key={item.key} value={item.key}> 
    {item.value} 
  </MenuItem>
))
```

It shows props.children element as a single value
[image]

The output is coming properly in this case:
[image]

Can anyone please show me the difference between these two?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra space before and after {item.value} it will work.

Comment: the question is about what is the difference between the two. the questioner knows it works that way

Comment: the difference between the two is the extra space in the first code, in the second one as it starts from the next line there is no issue of extra space. So by removing the extra space in the first code snippet it will work fine (as the second one)